# How to make a bootstrap nav bar disappear at a certain break point

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap navbar that is not responsive. I need it to completely disappear when a certain span is no longer viewable. I have found examples of changing the break point of a responsive navbar but I can't apply it to what I am needing.

```
<div class="my-fluid-container">
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom" style="background-color: #428bca">
        <div class="nav navbar-nav no-overflow" style="padding-top:15px">
            <span style="font-size: 16px;margin-left:20px;"><span style="font-size: 18px; color: white;">JobNumber: &nbsp;</span><span style="color: white">{{selectedJob.JobNumber}}</span></span>
            <span style="font-size: 16px; margin-left:50px"><span style="font-size: 18px; color: white;">JobName: &nbsp;</span><span style="color: white">{{selectedJob.JobName}}</span></span>
            <span style="font-size: 16px;margin-left:50px"><span style="font-size: 18px; color: white;">OriginalContract: &nbsp;</span><span style="color: white">$ {{selectedJob.JobOriginalContract  | number : fractionSize}}</span></span>
            <span style="font-size: 16px;margin-left:50px"><span style="font-size: 18px; color: white;">RevisedContract: &nbsp;</span><span style="color: white">$ {{selectedJob.JobRevisedContract  | number : fractionSize}}</span></span>
            <span style="font-size: 16px;margin-left:50px"><span style="font-size: 18px; color: white;">Budget: &nbsp;</span><span style="color: white">$ {{selectedJob.JobOriginalBudget  | number : fractionSize}}</span></span>
            <span style="font-size: 16px;margin-left:50px"><span style="font-size: 18px; color: white;">RemainingBudget: &nbsp;</span><span style="color: white">$ {{selectedJob.JobRemainingBudget  | number : fractionSize}}</span></span>
            <span style="margin-left:200px; font-size: 16px;"><span style="font-size: 18px; color: white;">Logged In As: @Html.ActionLink(User.Identity.GetUserName(), "Manage", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { title = "Manage", @style = "color:white" })</span></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When the last span of the div is no longer viewable I need the entire bar to disappear.

current css to prevent bar from collapsing and turning on a scroll bar.

```
.no-overflow {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    display: block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: auto;
    margin-top: 0;
    max-width:100%;
}
```

Comment: what breakpoint do you want to trigger the change?

Comment: go to texasicecarving.com   username admin password adminadmin    when you resize the width of the window I need it to disappear when the logged in username is no longer visible. It is turning into a scroll right now. I need that to change as well. I thought I had fixed that part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use media queries to affect an element in a given resolution, for instance, here, the user disappears a bit after 1500px (width of the browser), so with this code, you can hide the element that you want at that resolution, you have to put this in your styles at the end.

```
@media screen and (max-width:1500px){
    .no-overflow{
        display:none;
    }
}
```

The, to avoid the scroll on the bar, just change the overflow to hidden, that should do it

```
.no-overflow {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    display: block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: 0;
    max-width:100%;
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to use a % ratio as the trigger? Some of the users will be using large monitors and some will be using laptops. So using a specific resolution would not be consistent with different size screens?

Comment: Actually, this should work for every resolution, what this is doing, is showing the bar for those users with a resolution bigger than 1500px, and then hiding it for users with a resolution under 1500px, controlling this by % would be really hard to do, I even think that it wouldn't be possible AFAIK